# Youtube iframe on ionic app generate play icon background

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic3, webkit, youtube-iframe-api

I'm developing an app, using Ionic 3, thats reproduce a youtube video. As I want an embedded video I use an iframe where the src is the video's url.
When I test on an Android device, i get this before the video starts playing.

[image: video after playin on android device]

Is there a way to avoid that background? or make it personalized?
Testing it using "ionic serve" makes the background completely black, so it only happens running on an android device.

Comment: Hi @Juan Fernandez Sosa , I have the same problem, i dont see at ios simulator but I am seeing at android simulator. Did u find a solution? thanks

Comment: Hey!, i didn't find a solution for this. Maybe you can preload an image.

Comment: thanks, i also think maybe i should change to GIF background for my IONIC app, because now i have problem ios device (yes at simulator video background running but not on device) , dont play video even i applied safari video requirements..

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a temporary `<img>`, as soon as the user clicks on the img, the `<iframe>` tag is toggled on, with Autoplay = true.

Comment: because the video plays automatically without needing user interaction.

Comment: the interaction was the user click on the image, that image can be a video thumbnail. You can retreive youtube video thumbnails via youtube api.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [angular youtube-player](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/youtube-player/README.md). You can detect when the video is ready to play. If the video is not ready yet, just display an image or a spinner.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<img class="video-loading-cover" src="assets/images/home/ytcover.png" height="550" width="1400" [hidden]="isVideoLoaded" alt="">

<youtube-player #youTubePlayer (ready)="playVideo($event)" (stateChange)="onPlayerStateChange($event)" (error)="hideVideo()"
                  width="100%" height="540px" [playerVars]="playerVars" [videoId]="videoId"></youtube-player>
```

TS:

```
    @ViewChild('youTubePlayer') youTubePlayer: YT.Player;
      isVideoLoaded: boolean;
      videoId = 'your video id';

      // optional
      playerVars: YT.PlayerVars = {
        autoplay: AutoPlay.AutoPlay,
        loop: Loop.Loop,
        playlist: 'yourPlaylist',
        controls: Controls.Hide,
        enablejsapi: JsApi.Enable,
        origin: window.location.origin,
        rel: RelatedVideos.Hide,
        iv_load_policy: IvLoadPolicy.Hide,
        autohide: AutoHide.HideAllControls,
        showinfo: ShowInfo.Hide
      };

  ngOnInit() {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  }

onPlayerStateChange(el) {
    this.youTubePlayer.mute();
    switch (el.data) {
      case -1:
      case 2:
        this.youTubePlayer.playVideo();
        break;
      case 1:
        this.isVideoLoaded = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  hideVideo(): void {
    this.isVideoLoaded = false;
  }

  playVideo(event): void {
    this.youTubePlayer.mute();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.youTubePlayer.playVideo();
    }, 10);
  }
```

Note that in my example when the youtube video is loading it will call the (error)="hideVideo()" function and an image will be displayed. When it is available it will automatically hide the image and play the video.